# How to connect With Exiting Database

Tags: java, sqlite, database-connection

At first i had create a database called as "DataBase" using Firefox SQLite Manger extension.Now, I want to connect to that  database through a java program in order to traverse the whole database.
In order to connect database, i have found a way like this on the internet.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
public class ConnectJDBC3 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    String databaseURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DataBase";  //just change the databasename.
    String user = "Newaj_69"; //Here i have given only the user name of the pc
    String password = ""; //As i have no password in the pc
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL, user, password);
        if (conn != null) {
            System.out.println("Connected to the database");
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Could not find database driver class");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred. Maybe user/password is invalid");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
  }}
```

But still can't access the database.Now i want to know whether my process is correct or not? If not, the it would be very helpful with any kind of suggestion.

Comment: I'd recommend some example that uses SQLite, not MySQL.

Comment: Plz do recommend.Thanks in advace